# Removing users' personal information from message posts in php

Tags: php, email, codeigniter, messaging, phone-number

I have implemented a php/codeigniter messaging system and want to prevent users from posting their phone numbers, addresses, e-mails, websites or anything else that might allow for user contact outside of our messaging system.

Does anyone know of any available plugins or code that would remove such personal information from text?

Thanks

Comment: I can't imagine you have a good reason for doing this, but it's ultimately futile without moderation by a human. Make it against your forum rules to post personal info and ban accounts that do so.

Comment: How would you handle a situation where someone posts their phone number as "five 55 eight 7 two three"?

Comment: It's to help our human moderators. I know I can implement such a system, I was mostly wondering if anything out there already existed that would be decently intelligent enough to remove at least some things. This is for a payment site where we don't want the users to contact each other until they have proceeded with their transactions through our site. If they can just deal outside our market place, why bother lol.

Answer (score 2):

It is really difficult task and you can't be 100% sure that you'll prevent submitting such information.

You can easily prevent from posting emails and urls (in ISO standart form, of course), but it will be real pain in the ass for phone numbers and addresses.

`email@email.com` can be represented as `email at email.com` or `email[at]email.com` etc.

`http://www.google.com` can be represented as `google dot com` etc.

Validating addresses seems me to be unresolvable task at all Green st. 1-1 = st. Green 
house #1, flat#1; It's almost impossible to validate such strings.

Phone could be faked as well (1 121 123 43 23 => 1 one-two-one ...).

I advice you to simplify your task. It is real wasting of time, imho.

PS: If you'll decide to solve this task, then `regular expressions` will help you a lot and it will be **invaluable experience** that will make your developer skill higher!

Comment: I would think that after so many years of php being available and forums, that somebody would've come up with some kind of decent filtering system. If no one knows, then I can delete most major email provider names from the text which would deter many from listing their e-mail. Or even just flag the user that we think we've detected a phone number or an e-mail. Oh and we need it because we're losing transactions by people discussing outside of our marketplace. Anyone else have a moderate solution?